# tools to generate ejb3 interfaces

Tags: jboss, migration, ejb, weblogic

Currently we have applications developed , by using EJB2.0 running on weblogic server . i want to migrate those applications to jboss 7 .

Xdoclet,ejbgen tools were used to generate Ejb 2.0 artifacts .I just want to know are there any tools similar to xdoclet,ejbgen  that can be used to generate ejb3.0 and jboss relevant artifacts and deployment descriptors .

or can we use the same tools to generate ejb3.0 artifacts ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: If you use IntelliJ IDEA then try its option "Apply EJB 3.0 style". This is quite handy for migration tasks and it helped me a lot.

Comment: But we are using eclipse ide , is there any plugin to do so ?